# No pricing tiers?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to work through a demo Mobile App project, using Azure's Mobile Services.

[Create an iOS app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-preview/)

The instructions point me to Microsoft's [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), and they simply aren't working for me.

First problem was that the instructions for creating a database didn't seem to work, but I was able to step out and create a new database, and then select that successfully.

What has me stuck now is choosing the pricing tier.  It shows a pane titled "Choose your pricing tier", but the pane is empty. No pricing tiers are visible.

Any idea as to what I need to do, in Azure, to configure pricing tiers?

Comment: Do you want to use Mobile Services or App Service Mobile Apps? Mobile Apps is the next evolution of Mobile Services and is still in early preview, so you'll see some experience issues (we have some big updates coming soon :) ). If you want Mobile Services, use the classic portal.

Comment: If you want to use Mobile Apps, let me know and I'll try to help walk you through it.

Comment: What I want is a simple demo demonstrating how to sync an IOS app to a SQL database in Azure.  I thought the link above would do that. I'm fine with using Mobile Services. Is there a demo available?

Comment: Yup. Just use the manage.windowsazure.com portal and follow the https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-ios-get-started/ tutorial